# Sum of harmonic number divided by k

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to show the following equation

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} H_k = \frac{1}{2} (H_n^2 + H_n^{(2)})$

where $H_k$ is the k-th harmonic number and $H_k^{(2)}$ is the second generalized harmonic number.

I tried summation by parts

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} H_k = H_n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (H_{k+1}- H_k) \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i} 
 = H_n^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1} H_k $

but now I've no idea how to bring $H_k^{(2)}$ in the equation. Can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{H_k}k=\sum_{1\le j\le k\le n}\frac1{jk},$$
$$H_n^2=\sum_{1\le j, k\le n}\frac1{jk},$$
$$H_n^{(2)}=\sum_{1\le j=k\le n}\frac1{jk}$$
etc.